# Decay rates, time-energy uncertainty, and photon spectrum in two-level system

Tags: atomic-physics, dipole, photon-emission, two-level-system

This question concerns mainly a few statements from the following article https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.94.063839.

It states: "Early studies of two-level quantum systems used two-level atoms or ions isolated in high vacuum. The upper-state population decays at a rate $1/T_1 = \Gamma_1$, while the transition dipole in these systems decays at half the rate: $1/T_2 = \Gamma_2 = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma_1$. Here $T_1$ is the upper-state lifetime and $T_2$ the coherence time of the system. Such an atom or ion prepared in the excited state subsequently emits a photon of spectral width $\Gamma_1$, and these photons are indistinguishable..."

They also refer to $\Gamma_1$ as the longitudinal and $\Gamma_2$ as the transverse decay rates, respectively.

I have the following questions regarding this:

1. What is the decay rate of the transition dipole and why is it half the decay rate of the upper state? Furthermore, why do they refer to the decay rates as longitudinal and transverse?
2. How does the decay rate of the upper state lead to a photon spectral width of $\Gamma_1$? My confusion arises because I understand the lifetime as the time within which a $\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right)$ fraction of photons are emitted after excitation. So a photon might be emitted before or after the lifetime but how does this statistic define the spectrum of the photon?

I am working with single photon emission of DBT doped Anthracene nanocrystals, and they have a lifetime of about 3.7 ns which corresponds to a photon spectral width of 270 MHz following the above. **But it's not like each photon is 3.7 ns long in time?!** So I don't think this is the correct way to look at it.

I hope the questions are understandable.